# I am looking for a tool that uses Jira , Github and other data to show developer productivity

Tags: software-development, software-testing, code-analysis, code-coverage

I am looking for a tool that shows the following data by dev team or project:

- cycle time - how long it takes from PR to commit
- deploys
- incidents
- bugs / defects per commit

So far I have only found https://linearb.io/ , does anyone know any other ones?

Comment: this question seems to be asking about one specific interperetation of "developer productivity". There may be other solutions and posts online that discuss this topic more broadly that can also be useful for your specific case

Answer (score 1):

Because "productivity" is more subjective, then it really depends on how you interperet it. A company may define it as the amount of revenue produced, lines of code written, number of commits made .etc.

However, the major problem with some of these metrics, particularly the ones relating to commits, issues closed, tickets resolved .etc, is that, [once a measurement or statistic becomes a target, it ceases to be a good measurement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodhart%27s_law). If developers are paid based on "productivity" as defined by these metrics, then it becomes easy to game the system by taking what would have been one commit change and making it into dozens of commits, or filing more and more issues or tickets for smaller and smaller things.

All of this can actually take away from developer productivity since developers are now spending more time making commits or filing and closing issues.

There are many great posts that I have seen (but cant remember specific links for) discussing the topic of how to measure developer productivity at length that may be worth a read and may contain some software recommendations too.

Edit: [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/173077/alternative-metrics-for-software-development)s answers also seem to go over this and suggest some alternative metrics, but not a ton of software for doing this.